# Best way to find the most maximum sum of a range in array

Tags: python, arrays, sum, logic, range

What is, in Python, the best way to find the maximum sum of elements in a range of an array?

e.g. one array `[1,-3,2,5,-5]`

What is the range that the sum of elements is the most positive of any other range in the array? The result has to be the indexes of start and end position of the array.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem

Comment: The most optimal solution is **right there** in the above Wikipedia article -- In Python. I doubt you can get better than ``O(n)``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I first learned about this problem via Jon Bentley's book. To handle list with negative numbers, I added my own modification:

```
def largest(sequence):
    """
    This is based on Bentley's Programming Pearls chapter 8.
    My modification: if the sequence is all negatives
    then max is the largest element    
    """
    max_so_far = max_up_to_here = 0
    largest_element = sequence[0]
    all_negatives = True

    for element in sequence:
        max_up_to_here= max(max_up_to_here + element, 0)
        max_so_far = max(max_so_far, max_up_to_here)
        largest_element = max(largest_element, element)
        if element >= 0:
            all_negatives = False

    if all_negatives:
        return largest_element
    return max_so_far
```